# Problems adding multiple views into a layout

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to add multiple views of the same layout. however, when doing the below code I am getting Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

What am i doing wrong? thanks!

```
class GetTrackTimer extends TimerTask {

            Activity act;
            View RootView;
            public GetTrackTimer(Activity ctx, View RootView)
            {
                this.act = ctx;
                this.RootView = RootView;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {

                act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {


                        if (TrackItems.getInstance().items == null)
                            return;

                        LinearLayout items = (LinearLayout) RootView.findViewById(R.id.itemslist);
                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) act.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        for (int i = 0; i < TrackItems.getInstance().items.length; i++)
                        {

                            View  itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.track_item,null);
                            TextView tv=  (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
                            tv.setText(TrackItems.getInstance().items[i].Item.ID + "");

                            items.addView(tv);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your TextView tv is already a child of the inflated itemView, so you can't add it as a child to another view.

Try `items.addView(itemView);` instead of `items.addView(tv);`

Answer (score 1):

That's because you cannot multiple parent layout for single child element..

In here, `items.addView(tv);`  your `tv` is added multiple times, hence the error..